# Importing a table from one site to another

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to display a table from a site onto my site with an automatic updater. Would this be possible with PHP or Javascript? I've tried parsing the data into a google sheet, and later displaying the google sheet on my site but I feel like there is an easier way. The table I'm trying to display is here https://ahlhaxball.000webhostapp.com/table/table/ labeled "League Table"

Comment: Anything is possible! I would suggest looking into PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you want to regularly fetch the table's contents. That said, Stack Overflow's focus is in solving specific issues with programming, not building code from scratch. Please try to achieve your goal and if / when you run into trouble, ask about it here! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP. If you want to do update it live without refreshing page (like updating every min or every sec) then you need to use PHP with Ajax. Ajax will help you to make calls without refreshing the page.